# Finding the max between max_over_time and sum queries

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, promql

I am trying to query a namespace in kubernetes in order to find the max between the requested cpus and the limit.
In one query I used max_over_time to find the maximum cpus requested over the last 30 days, and in the other query I used max_over_time to find the maximum limit of cpus used over the last 30 days.
I tried using the max() function to find the higher value between the two queries, and I also the a>b or b method.
Using the max() function resulted in invalid output, while using the a>b or b method resulted in the query returning only a (even though in some namespaces b should have been returned).
I am getting the same problem when trying to do the same with the sum function (in order to find out the amount of cpus used exactly 30 days ago).

Answer (score 0):

To find bigger of to metrics you can use following construction:

```
a > b or b
```

Here if `a` is bigger than `b` it will be returned by `a > b`. If said expression doesn't return anything operator `or` will return second part, in this case `b`.

For your case resulting query will look something like this:

```
max_over_time(my_requested_cpu_metric[30d]) > max_over_time(my_limit_cpu_metric[30d])
  or max_over_time(my_limit_cpu_metric[30d])
```

Comment: I tried using it but only received a (even when i was meant to receive b)

Comment: @nadavyaf, shouldn't be. See this [demo](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/graph?g0.expr=sum(node_cpu_seconds_total%7Bmode%3D%22nice%22%7D)&g0.tab=0&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=6h&g1.expr=sum(node_cpu_seconds_total%7Bmode%3D%22softirq%22%7D%20*%2042.71%20%2F%2031)&g1.tab=0&g1.stacked=0&g1.range_input=6h&g2.expr=sum(node_cpu_seconds_total%7Bmode%3D%22nice%22%7D)%3Esum(node_cpu_seconds_total%7Bmode%3D%22softirq%22%7D%20*%2042.71%20%2F%2031)%20or%20sum(node_cpu_seconds_total%7Bmode%3D%22softirq%22%7D%20*%2042.71%20%2F%2031)&g2.tab=0&g2.stacked=0&g2.range_input=6h)

Comment: @nadavyaf, don't ask additional unrelated to answer questions in comments: this is not how comments work. If after receiving an answer you understood that your question is unclear or is missing crucial detail, edit your question and add needed details.

Comment: @nadavyaf, if you have completely unrelated question (like in this case) consider asking another question (after due diligence). I'm pretty sure question you want to ask is already been answered on this site.